# Setting the width of a Google Docs Add-on sidebar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, sidebar, add-on

I'm creating a [custom sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) Google Docs add-on, but can't [set its width](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setWidth(Integer)). I have *not* published the addon as a web app.

Here's the code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello!</b>')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('How wide is this?')
      .setWidth(600);  // or 200; neither works - width is always 300px
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

And here's what I get: always a 300-px wide sidebar:

[image]

Here's the [test document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zQZgwUiglIP2-2bjA9NpR7l-whg7GcmEGDAfGwpf5wU/edit)

Comment: As mentioned in this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showSidebar(Object), sidebars shown by scripts are 300 pixels wide.

Comment: An alternative, it's possible to use a [modeless dialog box](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodelessdialoguserinterface-title)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showSidebar(Object)), sidebars shown by scripts are 300 pixels wide.

Comment: Why does [the documentation on setWidth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setWidth(Integer)) not mention anything about the 300px fixed size?